# Insert statement in access gives error

Tags: ms-access, vba, sql-insert

I have been working on creating an extremely simple database with only 4 tables and only a few pieces of information per column. One of my tables is called "Customer" and inside of this table there or 4 columns for information. [image]

I have a button on my "AddCustomerForm" that runs the following command

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Customer(Customer ID, Email, Identifier) " & _
 = VALUES(Customer ID, Email, Identifier)  
End Sub
```

My Add customer form looks like this:
[image]

Could someone please point out what I am messing up? The error I receive is :

Syntax error.

Comment: Location field matches either Colorado Springs or Denver. these choices are available based on a Business table that defines a business ID of 1 or 2 to these locations.

Comment: @miroxlav I made some modifications and added the VALUES, I just failed to write it. I have updated the question.

Comment: I also removed trying to insert Location because I have that table mapped to an ID that represents a location in another table.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few issues I see - is [Customer ID] an autonumber field? If so don't include it.

Also - if you're running a Manual Insert I assume your form is NOT bound to your table, though I begin to wonder why Customer ID is shown on the form as being editable?

Finally it looks like Location is a numeric ID belonging to ID field of the Location dropdown that fills in the Business ID field

This will help you debug your SQL and show us what's wrong

Add it to your button and show us the value shown in Immediate Window when the code halts

```
    Dim strSQL as string
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Customer ([Customer ID], Email, Identifier) VALUES (" _
    & me.[Customer ID] & ",""" & Me.[Email] & """,""" & Me.[Identifier] & """)"
    Debug.print strSQL

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

If Customer ID is AutoNumber try this instead (assuming form is UNBOUND) and Location is ID value of first column of dropdown

```
    Dim strSQL as string
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Customer (Email, Identifier) VALUES (" _
    & me.[Customer ID] & ",""" & Me.[Email] & """, & Me.[Identifier] & ")"
    Debug.print strSQL

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Could not get this working so I am summing it up to my lack of knowledge and understanding. Once I go through my database and rework the tables/rows and relearn the separate pieces, I will gladly come back and accept an answer. Until then +1 :). Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: I added a pair of double quotes to wrap Email value - maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Customer ([Customer ID], Email, Identifier) VALUES([Forms]![MyFormName]![CustomerIDTextboxName], [Forms]![MyFormName]![EmailtextboxName], [Forms]![MyFormName]![IdentifierTextboxName]);"  
End Sub
```

Access requires brackets around any field name with a space. I also deleted the `=` before `VALUES` and changed the values to reference your form controls, which you will have to name appropriately. You also need a semi-colon to complete the statement and need to close your double-quotes.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx) page might help with syntax.

Comment: I did what you suggested and this is what I came up with. `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Customer ([Customer ID], Email, Identifier) VALUES([Forms]![AddCustomerForm]![Customer ID], [Forms]![AddCustomerForm]![Email], [Forms]![AddCustomerForm]![Identifier]);"`

Comment: I receive an error of "Too few perameters expected 3". This confuses me as I explicitly called out 3 (Customer ID, Email, and Identifier)

Comment: @bluerojo make sure your form is in form view and all of the referenced controls are not null.

Comment: Use of `me` might have been easier and the semicolon is optional

Comment: @LiamH +1 for `Me` but I don't think we should consider the semi-colon optional. Technically you are correct. but it's bad practice to omit it especially when working on any syntax error.

Comment: In other DBMS' I would completely agree, but not in access.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Could not get this working so I am summing it up to my lack of knowledge and understanding. Once I go through my database and rework the tables/rows and relearn the separate pieces, I will gladly come back and accept an answer. Until then +1 :). Thank you very much for your assistance!